# Why I am getting error while doing SNMP walk?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am doing snmp walk using following php code

```
<?php
  $session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_1, "10.221.11.123", "community");
  $fulltree = $session->walk(".");
  print_r($fulltree);
  $session->close();
?>
```

On execution, I am getting following error

***PHP Warning:  SNMP::walk(): Error in packet at 'SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.77.1.1.3.0': (genError) A general failure occured in /opt/test/test.php on line 3***

Just for more info, the snmpwalk is done to a windows 2022 server machine hosted on ec2.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: If you find a good SNMP book and learn more about genErr, you will see the error is on agent side and there is nothing to fix on PHP side. Investigating agent side issue is not programming related and you should ask server administrators for help.